# How to load XML data on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I created a sample code to view xml data. When the page is loading, my current code load full xml file. But I need to load XML file after the button click. How can I fix the issue?

here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"contact.xml",
        dataType:"xml",
        success:showCD
    });
});

function showCD(xml){
    xml = $(xml).children();

    $(xml).children().each(function () {                    
        let TITLE = $(this).find("TITLE").text();
        let ARTIST =$(this).find("ARTIST").text();
        let COUNTRY = $(this).find("COUNTRY").text();
        let COMPANY =$(this).find("COMPANY").text();
        
        let html = `<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
                      <p>${TITLE}</p>
                      <p>${ARTIST}</p>
                      <p>${COUNTRY}</p>
                      <p>${COMPANY}</p>
               </div>     </div>`;

              
            $("#xmldata").append(html);
        
    });
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
  <input type="button" value="View All" id="myButton1" class="reveal" style="float: right;"  onclick="toggler('toggle_container');">

 <div id="toggle_container" class='hide'>
      <div class="block">
       <div class="row" id="xmldata"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
</section>
```

[Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/GVLGcCvhGiqqRVQf?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a click event listener to the `button` and put the `AJAX` request inside the handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // adding click event listener to the button
    $('#myButton1').on('click', function() {
        // make the AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"contact.xml",
            dataType:"xml",
            success:showCD
        });
    });    
});

function showCD(xml){
    xml = $(xml).children();
    
    $("#xmldata").empty();
    xml.each(function () {                    
        let TITLE = $(this).find("TITLE").text();
        let ARTIST =$(this).find("ARTIST").text();
        let COUNTRY = $(this).find("COUNTRY").text();
        let COMPANY =$(this).find("COMPANY").text();
        
        let html = `<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
                      <p>${TITLE}</p>
                      <p>${ARTIST}</p>
                      <p>${COUNTRY}</p>
                      <p>${COMPANY}</p>
               </div>     </div>`;

        $("#xmldata").append(html);      
        
    });
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
  <input type="button" value="View All" id="myButton1" class="reveal" style="float: right;"  onclick="toggler('toggle_container');">

 <div id="toggle_container" class='hide'>
      <div class="block">
       <div class="row" id="xmldata"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you. Once I click the button, The code is working fine. But when I click the button again and again, It repeating xml nodes.

Comment: @Saji You didn't mention that in your question. I edited my answer, now only the newly fetched data will appear(we empty the container then append the data each time the button is clicked).

Comment: Sorry for mistake. Now It display another problem. It load only one node from xml

Comment: @Saji I edited my post, It should work as your needs.

Comment: oh dear, It is not working for me. http://next.plnkr.co/edit/wvWIvhHiG1Lor9Fk?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: but it's working in the link you provided ! Is there any error in the console ?